# How do I configure fixed length columns in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

In the previous EF, I could do this:

```
  entityTypeBuilder
    .Property(b => b.Foo)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(10)
    .IsFixedLength();
```

That would generate a migration with something like

```
Foo = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10, fixedLength: true)
```

However in EF Core there is no `IsFixedLength()`.

Is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently (EF Core 1.1.0) you can only specify column type directly: `.HasColumnType("char(123)")`

Please make sure your DB engine understand this value! It is passed "as is".

Also please note that you should write all required dimension/length/precision values here, because `.HasMaxLength()` value will be ignored.

Comment: That is a pity, EF Core does not seem "complete". Also, [according to docs](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/max-length) there is a max length...

Comment: EF Core is not a full replacement to E6, there are a lot of [issues on github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues). As a workaround, you may create own extensions method (`IsFixedLength(length)`) which calls `HasColumnType($"char({length})")` and control all this magic strings from one place.

Comment: About `HasMaxLength` - yes, it exists and working ok. But if you apply `HasColumnType("char(123)")` and `HasMaxLength(100)` to same property/column - 123 "wins".

Comment: I'm dealing with old code and have a problem with MS SQL timing out. I noticed that I had a problem with MS SQL / C# where it was using varchar(8000) instead of varchar(1). The code was using HasColumnType("char"), and one would assume this to be a single character, but it isn't.  If you use HasColumnType("char"), it will default to varchar(8000) on the DB side. char is fixed-size in bytes that can be between 1-8000, so it uses varchar(8000). Thanks for the answer.  This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this link explains the char vs. varchar side a bit more - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: very very thanks.  HasMaxLength ignore  when  I defined 
 (e=>e.ICC).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(30) and on Db set varchar(1) .But when defined (e=e.ICC).HasColumnType("varchar(30)").HasMaxLength(30) set varchar(30) on DB. EFCore3.1

Answer (score 18):

Actually, as for Version 2.1 this is implemented as:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(X).IsFixedLength();
```

Comment: Has this been removed? I Can't find this.

Comment: @Martijn make sure you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational somewhere in your dependency graph as the IsFixedLength() function is an extension method not in the main Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore assembly.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming to this issue like I did earlier today if you are looking for the IsFixedLength() function it is an extension method on the [RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions.cs#L226) class in the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) package

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a more recent example, in efcore version 6 you can implement an `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, and include the registration in your setup as follows;

```
public class MyEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(o => o.MyProperty).HasMaxLength(2000);
    }
}
```

And include the registration on your `DbContext` class;

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());//Your assembly here
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

I personally prefer this method because you separate out the concerns into different files, rather than having a monolithic DbContext.  This answer does not preclude the other answers, it's just an additional option.